# Set MySQL root password with command prompt on WampServer

Tags: mysql, wamp, root, command-prompt

I have installed WampServer Version 2.5 on my computer. I have been trying to set the MySQL root password using command prompt but it will not recognize my commands.

When I type the following:

> mysqladmin -u root status

I get the following error:

> 'mysqladmin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I was following online directions, in order to add the MySQL command prompt in WampServer to my Windows system path, and I think I did it right.

I also did a command line search for the 'mysqld.exe' file using

> 'dir mysqld.exe /s /p'

and I did not get any directory path.

Comment: I'd triple check that path again. Not that familiar with commandline windows, but if mysqladmin is not a command then it most likely cannot be found. Check that path :)

Comment: You may also want to make sure you restart or start a new shell (terminal).

Answer (score 1):

You should navigate in command prompt to the folder where is mysqladmin file. Try to find it with Find interface in Windows. Then try to `mysqladmin -u root status` or whatever you need.

Then you can add it's path to system variables, so it could be reached from every folder in command prompt.

Comment: The error came from the instructions. It said to title the system path by 'PATH'. But After I changed it to 'path' instead, it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a password to the `root` through mysqladmin.exe.

This executable is usually inside `<wamp path>\bin\mysql\mysqlx.x.x\bin`

Call the executable with the following parameters.

```
mysqladmin -u root password rootpassword
```